# Script throws error while scraping multiple values

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

My script is trying to scrape a website for 80000 IDs that are stored in a text file. When I run my code with a single o/p, it runs fine, but when I put all the inputs in a loop, I get an error.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("https://www.matsugov.us/myproperty")

for form in br.forms():
    if form.attrs.get('name') == 'frmSearch':
        br.form = form
        break

br.form['ddlType']=["taxid"]

with open("names.txt") as ins:
    tx = ins.read().splitlines()

    for x in tx:
        br['txtParm'] = x
        req = br.submit().read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('td', {'class': 'Grid_5'})

        for row in table:
            print row
```

Error:

`AttributeError: mechanize._mechanize.Browser instance has no attribute __setitem__ (perhaps you forgot to .select_form()?)`

Comment: I think the error means you can't use a statement like `br['txtParm'] = x` because `mechanize.Browser` objects aren't indexable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the loop wrong! Place it below the mechanize browser and then put a try catch at the end. It will work. Comment once u tried and it works.